# Cannot run Gcompris

Tags: 10.10

I installed gcompris on ubuntu 10.10 and when i tired to run it, it exited immediately. i ran it from shell giving the command gcompris and got the folowing message.

```
akn@ubuntu:~$ gcompris    
** Message: Binary relocation disabled

** (process:20588): WARNING **: exec_prefix NONE

package_data_dir         = /usr/share/gcompris/boards
package_skin_dir         = /usr/share/gcompris/boards/skins
package_menu_dir         = /usr/share/gcompris/boards
package_locale_dir       = /usr/share/locale
package_plugin_dir       = /usr/lib/gcompris
package_python_plugin_dir= /usr/share/gcompris/python
Infos:
   Config dir '/home/akn/.config/gcompris'
   Users dir '/home/akn/My GCompris'
   Database '/home/akn/.config/gcompris/gcompris_sqlite.db'

(gcompris:20588): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion `!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed
Segmentation fault
akn@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you found a bug due to the *failed Segmentation fault* message. But first try to erase the datas from `$HOME/.config/gcompris` and `$HOME/My GCompris` in your home folder, and try Gcompris again.

If you still see the error message, I really recommend you to open up a bug against the Gcompris package. There is a very good answer to [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) with a well illustrated path to report a bug, and a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) covering many possible scenarios on reporting bugs using [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/).

And don't forget to include in your bug report:

- Your Ubuntu version
- Gcompris package
- The reproducible details
- The log message (the output you got when you ran it from shell)

Thanks!

Comment: Adding more relevant info, as suggested by @JorgeCastro